# Trying to get the length of digits in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand why I am getting this error message.

```
error: data argument not used by format string [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
    printf("Enter card number: ", card_number);
```

here is the code that I'm trying to run the only difference between this and the code I'm copying is the name of the int.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
//Get card number from customer
    int card_number;
    int length = 0;

    printf("Enter card number: ", card_number);
    scanf("%d", &card_number);

    while(card_number != 0)
    {
        card_number /= 10;
        ++length;
    }

    printf("Digits: %d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use this to check if the length of the card_number entered is equal to a certain value. I haven't coded anything else due to this error. If I can understand better why I'm getting this error it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are passing `card_number` to `printf` when you don't need to

Comment: How many digits are you planning on entering?  On most machines, type `int` is only good for 9-10 digits, which is *not* enough for a typical credit card number.

Comment: @SteveSummit That's exactly the problem, read again please.

Comment: @JuanR whoops, misread, thanks

Comment: A few notes: 1. Given the number of digits in any credit card, using an integer variable will oveflow (unless this is a toy project, of course). 2. To get the number of digits you could use `floor(log10(card_number)) + 1` instead of the while loop.

Comment: Apologize for the program I'm trying to write has to determine if a credit card number is valid and which card company it belongs to using the number of digits input by the user. The digits entered are between 13-16 digits in length.

Comment: @Seigi90 We know. :-)  Believe it or not, you're not the first CS50 student to show up here asking about the Luhn validation problem. :-)  You're welcome to the same advice we give everyone else: it's probably easier to read the card number as a *string*, then work with it digit by digit.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yea I figured I wasn't the first but I'm just trying to understand better. I in no way want the answers outright. I tried looking around but just wasn't wording the question properly I guess. thanks for the advice tho I'll try that and see what I can come up with.